# Least Destructive New Heating System? Hot Water or Air?

Tags: heating, hot-water, radiant-heating, forced-air

I'm having some issues with my current steam heating system. I'd rather get it replaced with a whole new system, either forced hot water or forced air. The house was built in 1916, so I'd have to do mini-ducts if I went forced air (thin walls). I plan on feeding the system with the gas line I already have coming in.

I'm sure there will be some floor and wall tearing, but I'm curious to know how much, and should I really not put too much weight on this aspect.

The annoying part is, the previous owners did a renovation in 2009 but left the old steam system. Not that I have anything against steam but they didn't replace any of the pipes, values, air vents or radiators.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would maintain a hot water heating system for the increased comfort. Forced air is actually quite uncomfortable to people but it is cheap to install.

Just google "ideal heating curve" and you will see the many graphs comparing different types of heating systems. Like [here](http://www.alternativeheat.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/chart.jpg). And [here](http://www.adelaidehydronicheating.com.au/heatpump%20fotos/compare%20heating.jpg).

So you can choose, save money now and suffer or spend more now and be comfortable.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: I'm inclined to agree, the pain of installing a whole new hot water system will only hurt for a relatively short period of time.

Comment: Agree unless you are contemplating adding central a/c

Comment: It is now December 29 2016 and I am just reading your post.If you haven't replaced your heating system yet re-post. I have worked with steam, hot water and forced air.